# Star Rating system on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write simple star rating system with html , css and jquery. The Tricky part is that i'm getting each star from my cms and when I give class to 1 star , next stars will have the same class so i don't know how to make them light up like in example. 
The question is how to make all stars before light up like here

http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/

My html code:

```
<a class="rating" href="javascript:return false" onclick="star(1,6206,5,1,1431)"><span>★</span></a>
<a class="rating" href="javascript:return false" onclick="star(1,6206,5,1,1431)"><span>★</span></a>
<a class="rating" href="javascript:return false" onclick="star(1,6206,5,1,1431)"><span>★</span></a>
<a class="rating" href="javascript:return false" onclick="star(1,6206,5,1,1431)"><span>★</span></a>
<a class="rating" href="javascript:return false" onclick="star(1,6206,5,1,1431)"><span>★</span></a>
```

and some css:

```
    .rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: center;
}
.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.1em;
  color:green;
}
.rating > span:hover,
.rating > span:hover ~ span {
  color: transparent;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
   left: 0; 
   color: gold;
}
```

And Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5BbZh/

Comment: um, you know, there is a waaaaaay easier way to do this with sprite. just saying. Why mess around with JS, when pure CSS will do great!

Comment: But what is that way ? I know that will be working with 1 class rating and 5 spans inside, i asked because i don't know how to do it this way ;)

Comment: Sorry, I got busy. I'm posting a sprite start rating code now for you in an answer. I've used a hundred times, it's flawless

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is incorrect. You need to wrap your anchors with a div with the class "rating". Then you need to fix your css to reflect the changes. I would recommend learning about [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to understand what is going on here.

Using a class called "star" will generalize it, so you are not restricted to just "anchors", but you can use any other inline-element.

Here is the fixed HTML:

```
<div class="rating">
  <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(1,6206,5,1,1431)"><span>★</span></a>
  <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(1,6206,5,1,1431)"><span>★</span></a>
  <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(1,6206,5,1,1431)"><span>★</span></a>
  <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(1,6206,5,1,1431)"><span>★</span></a>
  <a class="star" href="#" onclick="star(1,6206,5,1,1431)"><span>★</span></a>
</div>
```

Here is the adjusted CSS.

```
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: center;
}
.rating > .star {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.1em;
  color:green;
}
.rating > .star:hover,
.rating > .star:hover ~ .star {
  color: transparent;
}
.rating > .star:hover:before,
.rating > .star:hover ~ .star:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
   left: 0; 
   color: gold;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BbZh/3/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, i have weird issue , my stars are lighting up from right to left, can you tell me why ? (of course i need them from left to right)

Comment: What is your jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust the sprite image so that it fits the container and there is no flickering. But other than that, it's all done. Also the stars I used are a hyperlink. Obviously you want to actually use an image in your root files.

[***DEMO HERE***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mcLqa/)